# How do I get the clicked() function that I made to work?

Tags: javascript, oop, onclick, p5.js

I'm following along with a Coding Train coding challenge, challenge #6: Mitosis. I'm stuck on the part where it is supposed to detect a click on one of the cells. If you put this into your web browser, you'll see what I mean - it says that `cells[i].clicked is not a function` and soon after it says `cells[i].moved is not a function` even though it was working just fine before. Can anyone fix it??? I am using the atom code editor, and the p5.js library. If you don't know p5.js, you might still know what is wrong... I already have it referenced in the code below though.

./index.html **USE THIS EXACT CODE, IT HAS REFERENCE TO P5.JS**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- This next part referneces p5.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.1.9/lib/p5.js"></script> 
    <title>Mitosis Simulation</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="script.js" ></script>
    <script src="cell.js" ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

./script.js

```js
var cells = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  //make two cells
  cells.push(new Cell());
  cells.push(new Cell());
}

function draw() {
  background(51);
  //make the cells move and show
  for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i ++) {
    cells[i].move();
    cells[i].show();
  }
}

function mousePressed() {
  //this SHOULD detect a click but it doesn't
  for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i ++) {
    if(cells[i].clicked(mouseX, mouseY)) {

      cells.push(cells[i].mitosis);
    }
  }
}
```

./cell.js ***The code for a cell, I guess you could call it object-oriented programming***

```js
function Cell(pos, r) {
  //gives the cell either the argument pos, or a random place on the canvas
  this.pos = pos || createVector(random(width), random(height));
  //gives it either the argument r or the radius of 80
  this.r = r || 80;
  //gives a random rgb color
  this.c = color(0, random(150, 255), random(150, 255));

  //move the cell
  this.move = function() {
    //define the direction that it moves
    var vel = p5.Vector.random2D();
    //move in that direction
    this.pos.add(vel);
  }

  //show the cell
  this.show = function() {
    fill(this.c);
    noStroke();
    //display a cell at this.pos.x, this.pos.y with a radius of this.r
    ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.r, this.r);
  }

  //return true when clicked
  this.clicked = function(x, y) {
    //find distance between mouseX, mouseY and its position
    var d = dist(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, x, y);
    //if distance is in the circle, return true
    if(d < this.r / 2) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  //split in two
  this.mitosis = function() {
    //make a new cell exactly like its predeccesor and return it
    var cellss = new Cell(this.pos, this.r/2, this.c);
    return cellss;
  }
}
```

I'm sure it was a silly mistake or something, but be sure to tell me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in your `mousePressed()`: you aren't calling mitosis as a function, you're just saying `cells[i].mitosis`. When you do this, it doesn't run the mitosis function, it actually just returns a reference to the function.

```js
function mousePressed() {
  // detects clicks, and if there is a click, it runs the mitosis function
  for(var i = 0; i < cellLength; i ++) {
    if(cells[i].clicked(mouseX, mouseY)) {
      cells.push(cells[i].mitosis());
    }
  }
}
```

Some other things to note:

1. Creating a new cell with 1/2 the radius isn't actually making something half the size, it's actually makes something smaller than half the area because of the way 2d things work. Imagine you have a square, and reduce each side length by a factor of 1/2: it will have 1/4 the area. Actual halving of the area would require doing some complicated math with length of the diagonal. So you have to do a similar thing with pi, and Shiffman goes over this in his agar.io tutorial
2. It's best practice to reference all of your classes (or in this case, closures) *before* your main JavaScript code, like this in your HTML:

```html
    <script src="cell.js" ></script>
    <script src="script.js" ></script>
```